# mfc100d.dll is either not designed

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I compiled my program (blobtracking) and this error appeared.

```
C:\Windows\system32\mfc100d.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error.
```

Anyone know what should I do?

I did install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable dll (2005 and 2008 version). But it didn't work.

p.s: I use VS 2010 32-bit and OpenCV 3.0

Comment: Are you running your program on the same machine than the one you compiled it ? If that's the case, I don't think you have to install any redistributable package because your Visual Studio installation already has the right dlls. Note that the `d` in `mfc100d` stands for the debug version, which comes only with VS, and *not* with the redistributable package.

Comment: Ah yes, that answer some of my questions. Then can you give me any suggestion to fix this issue?